# Webview HTML5 video stops after app plays local audio in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, html, video

I made a WKWebView that plays html5 video with the video tag using swift for an iOS App. I autoplay video when the page loads but when i play a sound in the app, using AVAudioSession, the video stops.

How can I keep the video playing? I need to play local sounds in this app